# SQL - ISNULL or if not latest date

Tags: sql, date, isnull

I have the case when there are two date fields.

If one is Null then take the other one.  At the moment this is working fine with the below code

```
select e.EMPLOY_REF, ISNULL(e.PROB_DOCS_SENT, ec.USR_FINALPROB)
from EMPLOYEE_TABLE e
join EMPLOYEE_USERCUST ec on ec.EMPLOY_REF = e.EMPLOY_REF
```

However, it could be the case where both are filled and if they are I need to take the latest date as being the valid one.

How can I ensure it takes the latest date in the case that both dates are filled?

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: will there be any chance that both are null?

Comment: both could be null as well yep but if that case null return is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query, the advantage of this solution over a case when solution is that you can easily extend it with more columns

```
SELECT EMPLOY_REF, MAX(Date)
FROM (
  select e.EMPLOY_REF, e.PROB_DOCS_SENT AS Date
  from EMPLOYEE_TABLE e
  join EMPLOYEE_USERCUST ec on ec.EMPLOY_REF = e.EMPLOY_REF
  union
  select e.EMPLOY_REF, ec.USR_FINALPROB AS Date
  from EMPLOYEE_TABLE e
  join EMPLOYEE_USERCUST ec on ec.EMPLOY_REF = e.EMPLOY_REF
) tbl
GROUP BY EMPLOY_REF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - this works on MSSQL

```
select e.EMPLOY_REF,  
case when   e.PROB_DOCS_SENT is null and ec.USR_FINALPROB is not null  then ec.USR_FINALPROB
    else   e.PROB_DOCS_SENT is not null and ec.USR_FINALPROB is null then e.PROB_DOCS_SENT
    else   e.PROB_DOCS_SENT is not null and ec.USR_FINALPROB is not null and e.PROB_DOCS_SENT >ec.USR_FINALPROB then e.PROB_DOCS_SENT
    else ec.USR_FINALPROB end
from EMPLOYEE_TABLE e
join EMPLOYEE_USERCUST ec on ec.EMPLOY_REF = e.EMPLOY_REF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   CASE 
        WHEN Date1 > Date2 
        THEN Date1
        ELSE Date2
   END AS MostRecentDate
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE-WHEN in order to handle all the possible cases. In the case where both the dates are null, the following query will take today's date as value.

```
select e.EMPLOY_REF, ISNULL(e.PROB_DOCS_SENT, ec.USR_FINALPROB)
case when e.PROB_DOCS_SENT is null and ec.USR_FINALPROB is null then getdate()
     when e.PROB_DOCS_SENT is null and ec.USR_FINALPROB is not null then ec.USR_FINALPROB
     when e.PROB_DOCS_SENT is not null and ec.USR_FINALPROB is null then e.PROB_DOCS_SENT
     when e.PROB_DOCS_SENT is not null and ec.USR_FINALPROB is not null 
     then 
         case when e.PROB_DOCS_SENT> ec.USR_FINALPROB then e.PROB_DOCS_SENT
              when e.PROB_DOCS_SENT> ec.USR_FINALPROB then ec.USR_FINALPROB
         end
end
from EMPLOYEE_TABLE e
join EMPLOYEE_USERCUST ec on ec.EMPLOY_REF = e.EMPLOY_REF
```